# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in react

Tags: reactjs, import

When I am trying to debug my react application, it gives me the following error **SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module** for the **import React from 'react'** statement. I've searched google but there are different ways and I couldn't find something related to react.

Comment: Can you provide the code, what you've tried so far?

Comment: Can you please share the code which has the mentioned issue? Thanks!

Comment: I cannot actually share the code, it is a very large project. Can you tell me what are the possible scenarios of this occurence

Comment: how do you compile the project? create-react'aap, webpack + babel,..,... Check also the extension of the file. Sometimes there are mistakes between .js/.ts and .jsx/.tsx

Comment: The extension of the file is .js and it is the entry point in webpack.config

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62790930/2899767